# Send parameter to socket in swift iOS app

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, sockets

I am making chat application in swift by using [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) and `node.js`.

I need to send along the user name parameter with one socket method. I tried like below without sending parameter. This works good but i need to add user name parameter to get specific data instead of total data. sorry for silly question am new to socket concept.

```
socket.on("updatechat") { dataArray, ack in
   print(dataArray)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at `SocketIOClientOption`, there is a parameter called `connectParams`.

```
case connectParams([String: AnyObject]) // Dictionary whose contents will be passed with the connection.
```

So, all you need to do is to pass the parameters into the `config:` when your are creating your socket.

```
let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: [.connectParams(["username": "whatever"])])
```

Comment: hey thanks @dirtydanee, you are answer is correct to send params along with url. but i need to do it along socket.on method

Comment: @dirtydanee. I am very new to sockets. How can i connect to socket server ,i am using socket.io . Please guide me searching on this since couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for SocketManager, you can set it with SocketIOClientConfiguration connectParams.

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "socket_url")!,
                            config: [.log(true),
                                     .compress,
                                     .connectParams(["token": "- your token -"])])
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to connect via sockets using the specific parameter. And then you will receive events only based on restrictions. Like you will connect sockets with an user id, and then will receive messages only for that user. 
The implementation is different depend on the library that you are using for sockets. For swift I would recomand to use `Socket.IO-Client-Swift`.